# Responsive design for iPad and iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, responsive-design

New to design for mobile devices. How can I ensure, especially for iOS, that the browser is really using the CSS media queries I have built in and not simply re-sizing the page?

For instace, I'm trying to set a media query so that I can have different layouts in portrait and landscape views on the iPad, but it looks like Safari is simply re-sizing or zooming rather than loading the media query.

Comment: [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers - Mobile | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) – might need to set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` for that to work across devices.

Answer (score 4):

I use these media queries for making iPad specific CSS

```
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 768px)
  and (max-device-width : 1024px)
  and (orientation:landscape) 
{
    /* iPad landscape style here */
}
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 768px)
  and (max-device-width : 1024px)
  and (orientation:portrait) 
{
    /* iPad portrait style here */
}
```

And similar ones for iPhone with different values.

If it's cumbersome to test on a real device you can check the design in the iOS Simulator (if you are on a Mac with the iOS developer tools installed). You can even use the Web Inspector in Safari to inspect the HTML, CSS, JavaScript in the simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only one link is enough!

http://bricss.net/post/22198838298/easily-checking-in-javascript-if-a-css-media-query-has

JS comes to your rescue by popping up alerts when each media query fires. You should know some JS to make these alerts happen...

Answer (score 1):

We have to target particular mediaqueries to handle this situation. I suggest you to read [this article](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/).